# PimaIndiansDiabetes2 to classify Outcome about disease

Tags: r, statistics

```
install.packages('mlbench')
install.packages('MASS')
install.packages('pROC')
library(mlbench)
library(MASS)
library(pROC)
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes2)
head(PimaIndiansDiabetes2)

summary(PimaIndiansDiabetes2)
newdata \<- na.omit(PimaIndiansDiabetes2)
summary(newdata)


# Fit the logistic regression model

model \<- glm(diabetes \~., data = PimaIndiansDiabetes2,
family = binomial)


# Predict the probability (p) of diabete positivity

probabilities \<- predict(model, type = "response").

I understand this code , but why some refference chosse probablity \>0.5

predicted.classes \<- ifelse(probabilities \> 0.5, "pos", "neg")
head(predicted.classes)


# Select only numeric predictors

mydata \<- PimaIndiansDiabetes2 %\>%
dplyr::select_if(is.numeric)
predictors \<- colnames(mydata)


# Bind the logit and tidying the data for plot

mydata \<- mydata %\>%
mutate(logit = log(probabilities/(1-probabilities))) %\>%
gather(key = "predictors", value = "predictor.value", -logit)



# scatter plot between logit and predictor value

ggplot(mydata, aes(logit, predictor.value))+
geom_point(size = 0.5, alpha = 0.5) +
geom_smooth(method = "loess") +
theme_bw() +
facet_wrap(\~predictors, scales = "free_y")

\#check the outlier
plot(model, which = 4, id.n = 3)

model.data \<- augment(model) %\>%
mutate(index = 1:n())

model.data %\>% top_n(3, .cooksd)

ggplot(model.data, aes(index, .std.resid)) +
geom_point(aes(color = diabetes), alpha = .5) +
theme_bw()

model.data %\>%
filter(abs(.std.resid) \> 3)


\#Multicollinearity

car::vif(model)
```

I try to make some data analysis using PimaIndiansDiabetes2

there is problem in outcome about this code !

also , if there exist some easiler code to make logistics regression .
please tell me .

I try to fix code , bacuase I self study learning . and I want to conect programming with staitics

Hope thats clear .

Comment: Hi Mary, welcome to stack overflow! One immediate correction is that you should remove any backslashes in your code, e.g. "\<-" should just be "<-"

Comment: Also, in the line "probabilities \<- predict(model, type = "response")." the period at the end should be removed

Comment: About choosing the threshold for classification, ideally the threshold is derived from considering the costs and benefits of each classification output and each actual class; then you compute the expected net benefit, and output the class which has greatest expected net benefit. This is a decision theoretic approach. When the benefit is 0 for a correct classification and 1 for an incorrect classification, the threshold turns out to be 0.5, which is widely used, but it's really only correct in this special case.